# Database connection string parsing in python

Tags: python, database, parsing, uri

Given a database connection string structure (such like one you can find [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Connection-strings--the-uri-parameter-)) what's the best way to parse a real URI string and get their component like user, password, database name and host?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a Python library for that:

- python 2: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html?highlight=urlparse#urlparse.urlparse)
- python 3: [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `urlparse`

*Python2:*

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

*Python3:*

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

***Example:***

```
r = urlparse('mysql://alex:pwd@localhost/test')

print(r.username)
# 'alex'

print(r.password)
# 'pwd'
```

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression (depending on the specific syntax)!?

For example:

```py
m = re.match('mysql://(.*?):(.*?)@(.*?)/(.*)', url)
```

is supposed to give you user, password, host and database in the groups 1 to 4:

```py
print(m.groups())
```

Or in one line:

```
user, password, host, database = re.match('mysql://(.*?):(.*?)@(.*?)/(.*)', url).groups()
```

Comment: that case, when accepted answer is not the best one;)

Comment: If we string contains database port, it is parsed together with host. For string "mysql://dbaas:f3nupd9Ig1iJO4QmGacWTAqKSW2qLWw2@100.81.0.179:3310/my_db", we would have host = 100.81.0.179:3310

Answer (score 4):

While `urllib.parse` provides general URL parsing, [SQLAlchemy provides a parser](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.make_url) specifically designed for database URLs (aka "connection strings"), providing a handful of [useful methods and properties](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL):

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import make_url, URL

url = make_url("postgres://user:pw@localhost/mydbname")

assert url.host == "localhost"
assert url.username == "user"
assert isinstance(url, URL)
```